# force line break in LaTeX bibliography (style file generated using makebst)

Tags: bibtex, line-breaking, custom-bib

I would like to edit my `.bst` file so that the bibliography outputs with

1. a line break after each author block (all authors) and
2. no left or right indent of wrapping lines.

So, instead of

> Mathieu, J. E., T. S. Heffner, G. F. Goodwin, E. Salas, and J. A.
>   Cannon-Bowers. 2006 “The influence of shared mental models on
>   team process and performance.” Journal of Applied Psychology, 26(3):
>   123–255.

I would like

> Mathieu, J. E., T. S. Heffner, G. F. Goodwin, E. Salas, and J. A.
>   Cannon-Bowers.
>   2006 “The influence of shared mental models on team
>   process and performance.” Journal of Applied Psychology, 26(3):
>   123–255.

The `.bst` file I'm using is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/900449/bibtex/bibliographystyles/asq.bst).

Even better: If you know of an official Administrative Science Quarterly style file, please point me to it. So far, no luck searching on my end.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459125/force-line-break-in-latex-bibliography-style-file-generated-using-makebst?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion with `biblatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
author={Mathieu, J. E. and Heffner, T. S.  and Goodwin, G. F.  and Salas, E. and  Cannon-Bowers, J. A.},
journaltitle={The influence of shared mental models on team process and performance},
year={2006},
volume={26},
number={3},
pages={123–255}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[minnames=10,maxnames=20]{biblatex}
%\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space !!1!}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\newline}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's close but not quite close enough; thank you for the suggestion though. i think i can tweak it a bit more to get exactly what's needed. will report back.